# Programatically save comma-separated string as value of taxonomy field

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, forms

I have a comma-separated string `$string` of the form "term1,term2,term3" and I would like to save it as the value of a taxonomy term field that is attached to my node. I have tried

```
$node->field_taxonomy[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $string;
node_save($node);
```

but this throws me an error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'tid' in taxonomy_field_presave()" coming from Taxonomy module.

What is the correct way to set the value of `$node->field_taxonomy`?

I also need that when `node_save($node);` is executed, taxonomy terms that had not been taxonomy terms before are created, just like it would happen when I set the value of `$node->field_taxonomy` via the user interface. I was expecting this to happen automatically when I set and save the taxonomy field value.

---

**Edit:** Actually, I am trying to attach taxonomy terms to *files*, but I thought that the analogous setup of nodes would be more familiar to most people.

I have attached a **description field** (`field_description`) and a **taxonomy field** (`field_hashtags`) to files via the user interface, using File Entity Module. I now want to upload files and fill in their attached fields using a custom file upload form, but on the custom file upload form there is only

- a field for the file itself (`$form['file']` of type `managed_file`) and
- a field for the description that the file should be given (`$form['description']` of type `textarea`).

My `CUSTOMMODDULE_form_submit()` function now defines `$submitted_file = file_load($form_state['values']['file']);`, i.e. as the submitted file, and `$submitted_description = $form_state['values']['description'];`, i.e. as the submitted description.

It then sets `$submitted_file->field_description[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $submitted_description;` and, as expected, when saving the file via `file_save($submitted_file);` the description field of the file is saved being populated with the submitted values.

However, before saving the file I run a custom function that returns a comma-separated string of hashtags (all words from the submitted description that start with '#') that were used in the description. I now want to set `$submitted_file->field_hashtags` as exactly those terms from the string that my custom function returns, just like I would enter a comma-separated string into a taxonomy field by hand from the user interface.

**Edit 2:** I further tried the following code from taxonomy.module

```
$terms = explode(',', $string);
$voc = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('vocabulary_name');
$vid = $voc->vid;

foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
  if ($possibilities = taxonomy_term_load_multiple(array(), array('name' => trim($term), 'vid' => $vid))) {
            $term = array_pop($possibilities);
        }
        else {
        $term = array(
          'tid' => 'autocreate',
          'vid' => $vid,
          'name' => $term,
          'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'vocabulary_name',
        );
        }

        $term_array = (array) $term;
        $node->field_taxonomy[LANGUAGE_NONE]['$key'] = $term_array;
    }
```

but this gives me "Error
Error message
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '$key' for column 'delta' at row 1:"

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `$key` when you store the value in the node array (`$node->field_taxonomy[LANGUAGE_NONE][$key] = $term_array;`). PHP doesn't expand variable names for single quoted strings, and besides, it's superfluous. Right now you're literally trying to store the string "$key" to an integer-type column, thus the error.

Comment: I can't believe this solved the whole issue. Thank you so much. I will now do some testing and get back to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

try that:

```
$terms = explode(',', $string);
foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
  $node->field_taxonomy[LANGUAGE_NONE][$key]['value'] = $term;
}
```

Comment: It gives me the following error: `Notice: Undefined index: tid in taxonomy_field_presave() (line 1889 of modules\taxonomy\taxonomy.module).`

Comment: Can you provide more information, for example in which function you use this code block etc.

Comment: Please see my edit in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This function worked for me:

```
/**
 * Return the term id for a given term name.
 */
function _get_tid_from_term_name($term_name) {
  $vocabulary = 'tags';
  $arr_terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name, $vocabulary);
  if (!empty($arr_terms)) {
    $arr_terms = array_values($arr_terms);
    $tid = $arr_terms[0]->tid;
  }
  else {
    $vobj = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($vocabulary);
    $term = new stdClass();
    $term->name = $term_name;
    $term->vid = $vobj->vid;
    taxonomy_term_save($term);
    $tid = $term->tid;
  }
  return $tid;
}
```

In your case it can be called like this:

```
$terms = explode(',', $string);
foreach ($terms as $term_name) {
  $tid = _get_tid_from_term_name($term_name);
  $node->field_taxonomy[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = array('tid' => $tid);
}
```

I just tested it for myself and it worked.

If you are using another vocabulary (different from **Tags**), then modify in the code above the line:

```
$vocabulary = 'tags';
```